# Disable control in CommandItemTemplate for RadGrid in different browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I am trying to disable the anchor control inside CommandItemTemplate of the radgrid. It is working fine in the IE browser but not in other browsers like chrome, firefox... Can anyone help me on this?

Code:

```
 HtmlAnchor ExportLink = new HtmlAnchor();
        GridItem[] items =
            this.rgCycles.MasterTableView.GetItems(GridItemType.CommandItem);
ExportLink.Disabled = true;
```

HTML:

```
 <CommandItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="AddRecord" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/_layouts/images/RMS/Pb - Add New.png" 
                    AlternateText="Add Record" />                    
                <a href="#" target="_blank" onclick="return ShowExportAppraisalDialog();" runat="server" id="Export">
                    <asp:Image ID="ExportPortfolio" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/ExportIcon.png"
                        AlternateText="Export Portfolio" Height="16px" Width="16px" />
                    Export
                </a>
            </CommandItemTemplate>
```

Comment: what is html output for this anchor?

Comment: <a id="ctl00_m_g_6d678b47_c4ab_48c8_8968_d659104cb553_ctl00_rgRevalidationCycles_ctl00_ctl02_ctl00_revalidationCycleExport" target="_blank" onclick="return ShowExportRevalidationDialog();" disabled="disabled">

                        <img id="ctl00_m_g_6d678b47_c4ab_48c8_8968_d659104cb553_ctl00_rgRevalidationCycles_ctl00_ctl02_ctl00_ExportRevalidationCycle" src="../../../../_layouts/images/RMS/ExportIcon.png" alt="Export Revalidation cycle" style="height:16px;width:16px;border-width:0px;" />

                        Export

                    </a>

Comment: This is the html Code in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

try with this code - Enabled

```
ExportLink.Enabled = false;
```